# Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\MailController, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I am getting the error

> local.ERROR: Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\MailController, because the name is already in use {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError(code: 0): Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\MailController, because the name is already in use at /home/.../app/Http/Controllers/SendMailController.php:0) [stacktrace] #0 {main} "}

I checked the name does not exist in any other class also the namespaces look to be okay in my eyes.

can someone help me, please?

```
<?php



namespace App\Http\Controllers;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Mail;

use App\Mail\SampleMail;



class MailController extends Controller

{

    public function index()

    {

        $content = [

            'subject' => 'This is the mail subject',

            'body' => 'This is the email body of how to send email from laravel 10 with mailtrap.'

        ];



        Mail::to('myemail@gmail.com')->send(new SampleMail($content));



        return "Email has been sent.";

    }

}
```

Comment: Loading the same controller twice perhaps? Your code works for me on an empty project.

Comment: how to check if loading the same controller twice?

Comment: Turn on debugging and show the backtrace, the error also says "already defined in...", post the full message.

Comment: this is what I get in log file:[2023-12-17 14:16:02] local.ERROR: Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\MailController, because the name is already in use {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Cannot declare class App\\Http\\Controllers\\MailController, because the name is already in use at /home/.../app/Http/Controllers/SendMailController.php:0)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}

Comment: Is it maybe a duplicate classname like what the error said?

Comment: The error message literally says where to find the existing name. Having class `MailController` in file `SendMailController.php` is wrong, it breaks class auto-loading.